# Value based on Multiple Dependent Drop Down Lists

Tags: excel

I created two lists in the **Sheet 1** (Excursion, Transfer), so I would like to use them as dropdowns in another sheet

[image]

In **Sheet 3** I added the following values: (I chose HD and Guide from the dropdowns and I added the value 283.50 in the 1st case and 210 in the 2nd)

[image]

In **Sheet 2** I want when I choose (from the dropdowns) HD and Guide then to return 283.50 and when I choose FD and Guide then to return 210 in cell F13. But it does not work. In all cases (HD and FD) it returns 283. Am I missing something in the vlookup which I wrote?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your VLOOKUP only checks Sheet3!B:B column for eg "Guide".

You should use database function with two row criteria for HD and Guide.
http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dget.php